# Clear all previous data, before loading new data into Elastic search using Java API?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, spring-data-elasticsearch

So, I have loaded data into the ElasticSearch and now whenever I upload new data it should initially delete the previous data and then upload the new data into the index.This must be a continuous process(service).

Comment: Simply delete your index prior to indexing data.

Comment: can you please elaborate it, Need to be done by Java API

Comment: Using the [`IndicesAdminClient`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-admin-indices.html) you can delete the index prior to recreating your index and indexing new document

Comment: so If I do that at the end of the day I will have so many indexes copy ??

Comment: sir, `client.admin().indices().prepareRefresh().get(); ` in this line what is client ?? which is Client client class or someother class ??

Comment: Why will you have copies if you are deleting the index and recreate them every time you need to freshen up the data?